# MongoDB - Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $meta

Tags: mongodb

This happened to me in 2.6.1 - So, in case anyone wanders into this error, I thought I'd write the answer out.

This first command worked fine, but the second one didn't.

```
db.test.find({$text: {$search: 'york'}} )

db.test.find({$text: {$search: 'york'}, score: {$meta: 'textScore'}} )
```

and threw up the error below

```
{"$err": "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $meta", "code": 17287}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out I just had the brackets in the wrong place.. and it should have read.

```
//This works
db.test.find(
    { $text: { $search: 'york' } },
    { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } }
);
```

Comment: This kind of errors happen also when I _stupidly_ call a method like `find()` with a query meant for `update()` when playing around in mongo shell, like `db.col.find({name:/something/},{$set: { name: 'something else'}}); // you can't use $set in find(), can't canonicalize query`

Comment: That can't possibly work, it's a malformed object. You'd get an error `Error: Line 2: Unexpected token {` for sure.