# MGO : Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $meta

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I am using the MGO to communicate with mongodb.
I want to search in a collection, and to sort the results by search score.

```
collection.Find(bson.M{
    "$text": bson.M{"$search": "mysearch"},
    "score": bson.M{"$meta": "textScore"},
})
```

But I get this error :

```
Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $meta (status code : 500)
```

When I only try with $text, it works.

I use the same bson structure than here :
[MongoDB - Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639896/mongodb-cant-canonicalize-query-badvalue-unknown-operator-meta?rq=1)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using a BSON "map" as the argument with the "projection" as part of the "query". Instead use the [`.Select()`](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.Select) method in chaining for projection:

```
collection.Find(
    bson.M{ "$text": bson.M{ "$search": "mysearch" } }
).Select( 
    bson.M{ "score": bson.M{ "$meta": "textScore" } }
)
```

Just like in the standard API examples, the "query" and "projection" portions are "separated" from each other.

Comment: @GuillaumeP Unlike the standard MongoDB `.find()` API implementation, "projection" is separated with mgo. It's an easy mistake to make. But the first hint should be "map" and not "list" as the reference API does.