# mongo-driver: Unknown operator: $meta

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to write this query `db.station.find({$and:[ {available:true}, { $text: {$search: "Romania SunFolk Radio"}}]}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})`

I wrote

```
filter := bson.D{
    {"$and", bson.A{
        bson.M{"available": true},
        bson.M{"$text": bson.M{
            "$search": query,
        }},
    }},
    {"score", bson.M{"$meta": "textScore"}},
}

opts := options.Find()
opts.SetSort(bson.M{"score": bson.M{"$meta": "textScore"}})
opts.SetLimit(1)

cursor, err := s.collection.Find(ctx, filter, opts)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

But this code return error (BadValue) unknown operator: $meta.
How to write this query correctly?

Comment: No, that question used https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo, but I'm using https://go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/

Comment: Does the same query work when typed directly into a `mongo` client connected to the same cluster? I mean, I would be surprised to learn that a Go driver (of whatever make) would somehow parse these tokens to convert them to _something_ passed to MongoDB; I would speculate it's the DB engine which actually interprets the queries, and the driver merely converts the query to BSON before passing it to the engine.

Comment: $meta is not a comparison operator and it's being used as part of your filter. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to add column "score" to result and sort by this column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$meta` operator is a projection operator not a filter operator (see [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/projection/meta/)). You're passing it in to the filter. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607964/mgo-cant-canonicalize-query-badvalue-unknown-operator-meta) actually is the answer to your question as already pointed out in the comments. If all you need is to sort based on the textScore, you can do it like this.

```
filter := bson.D{
    {"$and", bson.A{
        bson.M{"available": true},
        bson.M{"$text": bson.M{
            "$search": query,
        }},
    }},
}

opts := options.Find()
opts.SetSort(bson.M{"score": bson.M{"$meta": "textScore"}})
opts.SetLimit(1)

cursor, err := s.collection.Find(ctx, filter, opts)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: All is good but in sort need use opts.SetSort(bson.M{"score": bson.M{ "$meta": "textScore" }})

Comment: @Kitsor that's what the projection is doing. It puts the textScore into a field called `score` (make sure to add the other fields you want to the projection) and then the sort operations on the textScore contained in `score`.

Comment: But sort not working in case which you described.

Comment: What does the query output look like? If you add it to the sort, then you can remove the projection option. I updated my answer accordingly.